# SELECT-OPTIONS concept in programming languages

Tags: asp.net, web, search, sap-selection-screens

For those who know how a selection screen/select options works in SAP system:

Does anybody knows any open source project/product with the same functionality for different programming languages, specially for ones with web support?

I would like to create an advanced and dynamic search screen based on a set of database tables/view.

Comment: Select-options are supported in webdynpro. So you may stay with ABAP and develop for the Web.

Comment: Hello knut, Thanks for the response but I mentioned select-options from ABAP just to explain the functionality that I need in a different system. I'm not using SAP or ABAP.

Comment: I don't think anybody wrote this yet, I would definitely consider using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware that such project exists, but the screen part won't get you very far. Beside the very convenient entry of selection values the main feature of select-option is, that you can pass them to ABAPs build in Open SQL like

```
select ....
where field in selopt
.....
```

In other programming environment this is not supported, as such built in language construct is not available. I.e. on a web project if you have MySQL or some other DBMS storing your data, you'd have to get the values from the select-option from you screen and translate them to native SQL.

The screen part should be relatively easy to implement i.e. with jquery ui or some other GUI toolkit for webapplications, the hard thing will be the transaltion to native SQL.

This gets even worse considering, that in ABAP reports, Open SQL statements are used on a very high level, where in other programming environments you usually use a lot more layers of abstraction for your database access.

Comment: Thanks @hans-hohenfeld for your comment. I agree with you in almost everything you say.
However, the layer of abstraction for database access, Hibernate or NHibernate for example, should make the work easier, don't you think?

I understand how easy is to create selection screens + select data from the DB using ABAP. This idea is so good that should be used in different languages in my point of view. However the most important benefit for me is the user ability to have an advanced filter for anything he/she wants.

Do you think such a project would be helpful? I yes I might work on that.

Comment: @fabiopagoti I don't know if such a project would be helpful for anybody, but I guess so. Nevertheless, if you're interested in creating such a functionality for other environments, you should do so (and release it as open source :)